# Disable hotcorners in fullscreen mode

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces, fullscreen

**Question:**  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and I was wondering whether there was a way to disable hotcorners when either playing games or watching videos in fullscreen mode?  I find hotcorners very useful when working, so I'd like to keep them on when not in fullscreen mode.

**Useful info:**  Currently I have the top right as show desktop (implemented through the Unity tweak tool) and the bottom right as show workspaces (implemented through the CompizConfig settings manager).  I could implement both through CompizConfig if that would help, but I can't make any "show workspaces" hotcorners work at all with the Unity tweak tool.  As I understand it, this is a known issue.

There is a very similar question here, which doesn't have a proper answer:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2290467

I'm very new to Linux, although I do do a fair amount of other computing.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, disabling hot corners for full screen stuff is well possible with a script, but I am slightly confused about "Useful Info" part. How does that relate to full screen windows ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure whether Compiz and the tweak tool impliment hot corners in the same way - if they don't, then obviously I'll have to change what I'm doing or write two scripts....  Where would I start for writing this script?  It should I think in principle be quite easy; if(fullscreen==1){[stop hotcorners working]} or something, but am I writing in c++ or bash or what?

Comment: I'll write a script and post once it's working, don't worry about that. Tweak Tool changes Compiz settings so they essentially do the same thing, just different approach

Comment: Sorry to bump this, but I still haven't worked it out - did you get anywhere with that script?

Comment: sorry, I completely forgot about this question - university life took over my time.  I'll get back to you this weekend, if that's alright

Comment: Any progress? :)